# ASP.net c# help with chart control

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

i have the following dataset

```
NAME | GP   | ORD_GP | EXP   | TOTAL GP | TARGET
a      206     48      -239     15         1600
b      0       27       0        27        1520
```

iv managed to display the TOTAL GP on the chart using the code

```
    Chart1.BackColor = Color.Gray;
    Chart1.BackSecondaryColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
    Chart1.BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.DiagonalRight;

    Chart1.BorderlineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;
    Chart1.BorderlineColor = Color.Gray;
    Chart1.BorderSkin.SkinStyle = BorderSkinStyle.Emboss;

    // format the chart area
    Chart1.ChartAreas[0].BackColor = Color.Wheat;
    // add and format the title
    Chart1.Titles.Add("TOTAL GP Against TARGET  ");
    Chart1.Titles[0].Font = new Font("Utopia", 16);

    Chart1.Series.Add(new Series("TotalGP")
    {
        ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column,
    });

    Chart1.Series.Add(new Series("Target")
    {
        ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column,
    });

    Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;

    DataView dataView = new DataView(ds.Tables[0]);

    Chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(dataView, "NAME", dataView, "TOTAL_GP");
```

please can some one tell me how i can plot the target on the same chart ?

**UPDATE**

also how do i get the chart to show the values for each column ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to databind the second column to some source data

```
Chart1.Series[1].Points.DataBindXY(dataView, "NAME", dataView, "TARGET");
```

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/intl/tr-TR/apis/chart/